Can I access a specific component inside (tabs) folder in my root layout in React Native using Expo Router?
So basically I have a (tabs) folder in my application that contains these files: _layout.tsx, index.tsx and trainers.tsx.
The thing is, I want to make the root layout of the application dynamic based on whether the user is logged in or not. But if the user isn't logged in, I want to display only the trainers.tsx, instead of the whole tabs navigation, and I also can't make the trainers page as the index because it would make sense based on the business logic.
I have tried this but it gave me the error [Layout children]: No route named "(tabs)/trainers" exists in nested children: ["Login", "SignUp", "(tabs)"]
app/_layout.tsx
function RootLayoutNav() {
  const mockUser = false;

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryProvider}>
      <Stack>

      {mockUser ?
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      :
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)/trainers" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      }
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

